# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' giving error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is my code

```js
const currentTimeStamp = `${(parseInt(Date.now() / 1000))}`;
const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState<string>(currentTimeStamp || '');
```

it throws an error in production :

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.  TS2345

Comment: Hi Asif. What about currentTimeStamp.toString()?

Comment: please, show code of useState

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `parseInt()`, because `Date.now()` return already a number and also `Date.now() / 1000`.
`parseInt()` is complaining because it should be given a string instead of a number.

You can do:

```
const currentTimeStamp = `${(Date.now() / 1000)}`;
```

Comment: This is correct. Not sure why the downvote - `parseInt`'s signature is `function parseInt(s: string, radix?: number | undefined): number`. Even in normal JS it's a very bad practice to use `parseInt` with a number.